# macro to fill in empty cell with assigned value?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

let's say i have a worksheet with 5 columns and ~30,000 - two of those columns are timestamp formatted. both the TS columns have ~300 blank cells, which i would like to populate with a dummy TS value (1900-01-01 00:00:00) for later filtering. if i inserted an extra column for an IF statement, the formula would look like this, of course:

```
=IF(B2="","1900-01-01 00:00:00",B2)
```

however, i would rather use a macro to loop through both TS columns (let's define that range as B2:B30000, C2:C30000).

any help is much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` should be helpful. You can do this manually btw in a few steps, w/o using VBA.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! yeah, i figured i could just add filters and populated manually (it really wouldn't take long at all, you're right), but i've been trying to learn more VBA and figured this would be a good exercise. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully it will solve your issue.

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub Fill_In_Value()
    
'Turn off following processes to speed up code
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim Column1 As Long
Dim Column2 As Long


Column1 = 1 '1 = To Column A, this setup is easier to change the column later on
Column2 = 2 '2 = To Column B
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the worksheetname



lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in Column A

For i = 2 To lRow 'Loop from row 2 to last row

    If ws.Cells(i, Column1) = "" Or ws.Cells(i, "B") = "" Then 'If any of the column A or column B is empty then:
    
        If ws.Cells(i, Column1) = "" Then 'If column A have blank value then:
            ws.Cells(i, Column1).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00" 'Add dummy value
            
            If ws.Cells(i, Column2) = "" Then 'If column A have blank value, also check column B.
                ws.Cells(i, Column2).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00" 'Add dummy value
            End If
            
        ElseIf ws.Cells(i, Column2) = "" Then 'If Column A is not blank, B should be blank
            ws.Cells(i, Column2).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00"
        End If
    End If

Next i

'Turn on following processes to get back to normal state
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


MsgBox ("Complete") 'Message box to show when code is finished

End Sub
```

---

Faster version

```
Sub Fill_In_Value2()

'Turn off following processes to speed up code
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lRow1 As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim Column1 As Long
Dim Column2 As Long


Column1 = 1 '1 = To Column A, this setup is easier to change the column later on
Column2 = 2 '2 = To Column B
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the worksheetname



lRow1 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, Column1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in Column A
lRow2 = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, Column2).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row in Column B

ws.Range(Cells(2, Column1), Cells(lRow1, Column1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00"
ws.Range(Cells(2, Column2), Cells(lRow2, Column2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "1900-01-01 00:00:00"

'Turn on following processes to get back to normal state
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


MsgBox ("Complete") 'Message box to show when code is finished

End Sub
```